# How do I install Tensorflow v1?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to run code that was written with tensorflow v1 and I am struggling to migrate it to tensorflow v2. I thought it might be easiest to install tensorflow v1 but I couldn't find a tutorial on how to do that. Is it even still possible to install Tensorflow 1?

Answer (score 1):

Code written using Tensorflow V1 can be easily upgraded to Tensorflow v2 by following Tensorflow [migrate guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate).

And also convert Tensorflow v1 based code to Tensorflow V2 just by running upgrade code, to know more about this library see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/upgrade).

To install Tensorflow v1 version,

```
pip install tensorflow==1.15
```

Follow the [instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) mentioned to install Tensorflow.

Comment: this is no longer possible (installing tf-v1 in 2021)

Comment: Still we can install Tensorflow V1 version such as 1.15, 1.14, 1.13. Thanks!